# What did I do wrong in this Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, string, function, parameters

I wrote a Ruby script, but I'm getting a syntax error.

Code:
[image: code]

Output:
[image: code]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: There shouldn't be any spaces between the method name and brackets. Please paste code and output into the question. Don't use screenshots please!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
a.float_value_set (2.98, "+")
```

do:

```
a.float_value_set(2.98, "+")
```

or omit parentheses:

```
a.float_value_set 2.98, "+"
```

There can't be any spaces between the method name and the opening parentheses.

Comment: Not brackets, but parentheses.

Comment: @CupawnTae Nope. Ruby does not define the word bracket.